# How do I attach a shelf to an existing kitchen unit?

Tags: drywall, shelving

In the kitchen of our new house, there is a slightly unusual extension to the side of one of the cupboards where the wall has been covered by a flat piece of veneered chipboard, the same finish as  the rest of the units in the kitchen. It looks like it might have had a shelf in there at some point, but it is currently dead space and I'd like to hang some new shelves in there if possible:

[image: photo of backing board]

Behind the backing board the wall is drywall/plasterboard and I wasn't sure how to securely fasten a shelf bracket to the wall *through* the backing board. Normally on drywall I would use rawlplugs, but since I can't actually get to the drywall in this case, I wasn't sure if there was an alternative.

This second photo shows the unit to the immediate left of the area I'm looking at, you can see that there are some boxed in pipes that I don't really want to go drilling holes through if I can avoid it:

[image: wider shot of kitchen units]

Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: It would really help if you could add another photo that shows more of the adjacent area so folks can get a better idea of just how this "backer board" is positioned relative to the other cabinetry. It would also allow others to be able to much better recommend what type of shelf attachments would be appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelKaras thanks for responding, I've added a second photo, hopefully that makes things a little clearer? Please disregard the vodka and malt whiskey, they are unrelated to the task at hand :)

Comment: Sorry to say but you really did not step back enough to allow us to see if this is inside a cabinet, in a corner or what the dickens is going on here. Remember, you've seen the whole thing countless times but put your self behind our eyes and you see that what you've shown so far is way too zoomed in.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I had to sit in the sink to take the new picture, but hopefully this will be more obvious! I've added a kettle for scale!

Comment: That is much more helpful.

Comment: It looks to me like what you have there to the right side of the picture is what was the back and top of a cabinet that was once installed there but had its front, side, bottom and door removed. Maybe former owner thought the cabinet was too confining in this small area (must be small if you had to sit in the sink @^@).

Comment: Can you guesstimate how much weight the shelves might be holding?

Comment: It definitely looks like that's part of a carcass for a cupboard - have you looked to see if the full unit is still available, and use the "spares" from that to complete it? (assuming there's not a hob too close, to the right for building regs to allow the cupboard to be hung)

Comment: @MichaelKaras as far as I am aware it was always intended to be open like this, when we first moved in to the house there was a glass shelf in the middle that I understand was intended for a microwave oven, but it was at such an angle that it was unsafe to use, so I removed it. We definitely have no spare pieces.

Comment: @Rowland-Shaw please see comment above

Comment: @mikes anything above 5kg would make a big difference to our storage capabilities!

Answer (score 1):

Wall studs should be every 16". If you measure from the start of the wall where the pipes are, you should be able to hit a stud every 16" behind the backing board. I'm not sure what the pipes are that you have in your kitchen - venting maybe, but I would look for shelves that would be supported via studs through the backing board wall instead of trying to screw into the wall with the pipes.

Comment: this would definitely work if there were multiple studs behind the backing board, but in my case there is only one, right in the middle, which would make it difficult to fit a shelf bracket